# Hard choice when reviewing a low-quality answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Earlier today, while I was working the review queues, I encountered an answer flagged by StackExchage's automatic review software as very low quality. I agreed that [the post in question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47027/3066) was a low quality one, but didn't like any of choices given for me to proceed, which if I recall correctly, are: "looks good", "recommend deletion", "edit", and "skip". I didn't want to choose "looks good" because the answer didn't look good. I couldn't see how any editing would fix it. None of the reasons given under "recommend deletion" seemed to apply. So in the end I reluctantly chose "skip".

I'm bother by this. In my opinion the post was bad, but it was bad because it was way off target. But being a poor answer isn't one of the reasons found under "recommend deletion". On the other hand, it doesn't feel right to click on "looks good". Maybe my problem purely psychological. I would have been happy to click on button labeled "let it stand".

Is there any chance of having "looks good" relabeled "let it stand"?

Comment: I suppose you could comment and, perhaps, downvote.  It's the user's first answer, so I would hesitate to downvote immediately.

Comment: @MichaelE2. I agree with you about down-voting. I did not and have not down-voted the answer I used as an example. However, this isn't about one particular post. It's about the Close Votes review page.

Comment: @m_goldberg My first remark was the main point I wished to make about the review page generally.  As far as the queue goes, it seems the choices we have are to vote to delete, to vote to remove from the queue ("looks good") and to abstain ("skip"); we can also try to improve (edit, comment, down-vote).  I agree that "looks good" is too strongly positive for some LQ posts, but really it means not so bad as to warrant deletion.  The reason I mentioned the particular post was that LQ posts are often from new users who might be unfamiliar with the site's norms.

Comment: From the StackExchange procedural point of view, if the answer does not look good, you are expected to downvote. I've certainly become more mercenary in this respect lately. In this case it seems that the poster genuinely did not understand what was being asked for, and posted a guess that ended up missing the point. In this situation I usually think that a comment is in order, and if it isn't addressed by the poster, one can downvote or flag as not-an-answer later on. Other SE sites often do have downvoted answers; the main difference here seems to be that we usually try to get rid of them.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Every thing you say in your comment is reasonable, but you don't say what response I should make in the review queue. Trying to read between the lines, I guess you are telling me to click on "skip" and then go to the question and make a comment. Is my guess right?

Comment: In my opinion, you can reasonably either skip or choose "looks good", i.e. what I would interpret as "there is no compelling need for this post to be changed or removed immediately and it can be subjected to ordinary peer review". But, if you do the latter, for a poor quality post I would certainly also comment and/or downvote. My understanding is that the review queue is not really meant for judging the technical quality of posts; rather it is more of a pre-screening mechanism to remove posts that by their nature (irrelevant/inappropriate/ill-defined etc.) cannot be judged on technical merit.

Comment: In that sense I wouldn't object to having "looks good" changed to "let it stand". Arguably it gets the point across more clearly, and I'll admit to having been a little confused on this point in the past. Of course this assumes that my current understanding isn't totally incorrect.